# Bare Bones Twitter Feed for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter

I looking for a barebones twitter feed plugin for wordpress or how to create one.

I am developing a site that has a masonry design with recent twits spread through out the front-page.

All the plugin/widgets give you a highly style look and have each tweet right after the other. I just need the date it was posted and the twit line itself

EXAMPLE BELOW:[image]

I heard that Twitter limits your styling of tweets for the API, is this true?

Thanks

Comment: If they are snippets of tweets and not a timeline/feed i personally think it would be better to fetch them via the API and you could even make them into a posts for easily query-able or hijack the post loop and show them on specific times (their create date). Man this honestly feels like a good plugin idea, hell i might do it myself for giggles. :D

Comment: Twitter has display requirements which you should follow to be in compliance with policy https://dev.twitter.com/overview/terms/display-requirements - generally it is better to use the provided embedded Tweets and Timeline widgets that handle this for you via publish.twitter.com

Comment: Please note that this question is off topic: "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow* as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam" Ref [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)